# converting documents to zip file, Added files and downloading, but while opening getting error

Tags: c#, asp.net, zip, c#-ziparchive

1. Successfully adding documents in to zip add entry and downloading 
   it.
2. But while opening for example Doc1, Doc2 If i download
          only doc1 (download and view Successfull)
3. if i try doc2 it downloaded, but
          while opening(Cannot open file, It does not appear to be a valid
          archieve, Try again this is message when opened). If i checked both
         and downloaded and it's successfully downloaded and I can open it.

Any help greatly appreciated

```
ZipFile zip = new ZipFile();

foreach (GridDataItem item in RadGridSearchResults.MasterTableView.Items)
{
    int documid;             
    bool chec;
    CheckBox check = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("CheckBox1");
    DocDetails dd = new DocDetails();
    if (check.Checked == true)
    {
        documid = Convert.ToInt32(item["DOCUMENT_ID"].Text);
        Document document = Document.GetDocumentByDocumentId(documid);    
        zip.AddEntry(document.DocumentName, document.DocumentFileImage);

    }                      
}

var zipMs = new MemoryStream();
zip.Save(zipMs);

byte[] fileData = zipMs.GetBuffer();           
zipMs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
zipMs.Flush();

Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=docs.zip ");
Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
Response.BinaryWrite(fileData);
Response.End();
```

Comment: I think, downloading files directly from database and adding to zip causing internal errors, Does it possible to download to local folder and convert the full folder to zip and download and clear the folder data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by using

```
using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip;
```

by using (using Ionic.Zip;) this data is corrupting internally and not even throwing exception